# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 182-187: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, парсер

В Windows консоли при помощи активированной виртуальной среды запускаю анализатор, который сравнивает значения в БД со значениями в net-файле в кодировке cp1251 команда:python analyze.py [имя net-файла] [кодировка net-файла]

Падает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "analyze.py", line 151, in <module>
    analize(*sys.argv[1:])   File "analyze.py", line 93, in analize
    result = cur.execute(code_request)   File "C:\Project\model\foo\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 182-187: character maps to <undefined>
```

Часть блока кода (цикл) программы-анализатор, в котором падает ошибка:

```
for cps in xrange(0, len(columns), cr):
    code_request = u'''
        SELECT ATTRCODE
        FROM VSM_UDA
        WHERE ATTRCODE IN (%(columns)s)
        AND LISTID = %(list_id)s
        ''' % dict(columns=u', '.join([u'\'%s\'' % name for name in columns[cps:cps+cr]]),
                   prefix=prefix, table_name=active_table, list_id=list_id)
    raw_conn = db_engine.raw_connection()
    cur = raw_conn.cursor()
    result = cur.execute(code_request)
    rows = result.fetchall()
    result.close()
    uda_column_names.extend([row[0] for row in rows])
```

Я проверил файл парсинга. Кодировка установлена ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

нужно указать `result = cur.execute(code_request.encode('utf8'))`